# Angular2 Date filter C# Date?

Tags: angular

Is there a built in Date pipe filter to handle dates the way the default asp.net JSON serializer, serializes dates?

Here is the example format:     '/Date(1466624402557)/'

Otherwise I can write a custom pipe.

Per rinukkusu here is the custom pipe i've created:

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import {SlicePipe, DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({
    name: 'aspDate'
})
export class AspDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, arg: string): any {
        let slicedValue = new SlicePipe().transform(value, 6, -2);
        return new DatePipe().transform(slicedValue, arg );
    }
}
```

But am getting this error:

platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '1466624402557' for pipe 'DatePipe'

I've tried boxing the sliced string to a new Date() but that doesn't work either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the built-in pipes [slice](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-class.html) and [date](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html) to achieve this:

```
{{ '/Date(1466624402557)/' | slice:6:-2 | date }}
```

Otherwise go for the custom pipe route. You can use it like the `date` pipe argumentwise:

```js
@Pipe({
    name: 'aspDate'
})
export class AspDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: string, arg: string):any {
        let slicedValue = new SlicePipe().transform(value, 6, -2);
        return new DatePipe().transform(new Date(parseInt(slicedValue)), arg);
    }
}
```

In your template for instance:

```
{{ '/Date(1466624402557)/' | aspDate:'fullDate' }}
```

---

> **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/V3NXTQfu9hBcdv7ng8lp?p=preview) for example usage**

Comment: Thanks for showing this approach of chaining the pipe filters in code, I wouldn't have thought of that.  I'm getting this error though :

platform-browser.umd.js:962 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid argument '1466624402557' for pipe 'DatePipe'

Comment: Which Angular 2 version are you using?

Comment: "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",

Comment: Okay, I can reproduce it with RC.1 - this error is gone with RC.3, though!

Comment: Apparently in RC.1 the `DatePipe` only takes `Date` objects, no timestamp string/number format. I edited the answer and added a `new Date(parseInt(slicedValue))`.

Comment: ok i was missing parse int part when instantiating the js date.. thats why my attempt to box it was failing.  Thanks for this...  I was attempting to update to rc3 but node was failing to find router-deprecated module for that so i would have been stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent of my knowledge, No. You can refer to the [API of the date pipe in Angular](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-class.html) so you'll have to implement it yourself

---

## Update:

According to the [Changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) the numeric date one of the [features](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features) added is " datePipe: numeric string support " you can see the [related commit here](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/5c8d315)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `DatePipe`, you can directly check what it supports or not. Currently no support for that format:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5c8d3154d755f879d328739b78952fc88d38681f/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/date_pipe.ts